# Making a div fill a table cell in HTML5

Tags: html, html-table

I've got a div inside an HTML table cell, but I can't get it to fill the whole cell.

```
<body style="background-color: ButtonFace;">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse; border-color:Red;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div style="border:solid 1px green;background-color: Yellow;">
                            test
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
```

It has a gap, where the (grey) background shows through.

[image]

I'm sure it must be really easy to remove it, but I just can't figure out how.

Comment: Looks like `td` tag padding. Have you tried resetting that to 0? Alternatively can be the `div` margin. Impossible to tell exactly as we can't see all of your CSS, etc.

Comment: @Strelok Where were you three hours ago! Got it straight away- thanks!

Comment: Incidentally, there is no more CSS. What I've posted is all there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please apply

```
padding:0;
```

To the `td`

Or you may try to use

```
border-spacing
```

Comment: That's the answer, thank you. I feel like I should be giving Strelok the credit as he got in first.

Comment: I believe you should as well :)

Answer (score 1):

you have to set padding 0 for TD

```
 <body style="background-color: ButtonFace;">
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse; border-color:Red;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding:0px"> <-- Change
                            <div style="border:solid 1px green;background-color: Yellow;">
                                test
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add "cellpadding" for the table and set it to "0"

```
<body style="background-color: ButtonFace;">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table cellpadding="0" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse; border-color:Red;">
            <tr>
                <td >
                    <div style="border:solid 1px green;background-color: Yellow;">
                        test
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

-Nick